# Stop getting Netflix notification emails

Tags: account-management, notifications, netflix

Netflix wants to send me an email by default every time they receive a disk from me and every time they send one out.

How can I turn these emails off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of turning off these emails. The best you can do is set up a rule in your email client to filter them out and delete them if desired.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. just get an email account just for Netflix and never look at it.